# Owl Cafe in Tokyo where English is spoken?

Tags: japan, tokyo, language-barrier, cafes

I'm visiting Tokyo in late September and really want to visit an owl cafe. I've heard that it is best to go with someone who speaks Japanese as they usually give instructions etc only in Japanese. Are there any humane and well-kept Owl Cafes that can speak to me in English too?

For those who wonder ...

[image]

From link [here](http://www.buzzfeed.com/lukelewis/owl-cafes-exist-in-japan-which-is-yet-another-reason-to-move#.oyr9qZZxN7) supplied by Nate.

Comment: I read this and assumed that "owl cafe" was a colorful euphemism for something, but apparently it is simply  a cafe inhabited by live owls (the literal birds).  http://www.buzzfeed.com/lukelewis/owl-cafes-exist-in-japan-which-is-yet-another-reason-to-move#.tgKMKrA0M

Comment: Owl cafe as in a cafe that opens all night?

Comment: You need Owls that speak English too :-)

Comment: @NateEldredge If you think that's impressive, try the [polar bear café](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shirokuma_Cafe)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a review [here](http://news.yahoo.com/hoot-hanging-owls-tokyo-cafe-181741722.html) of Fukuro no Mise, which mentions an English set of instructions and an English speaker who works on Fridays. The review is from January 2015, so it's likely to be the same still. The shop's page (in Japanese) is [here](http://profile.ameba.jp/fukurounomise/)